# Python - separate files based on their content

Tags: python, python-2.7, shutil, os.path

I tried to move folders (along with it content) to new location based on string(country iso) located in text file.

Text files look like this

```
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|1|48|89|36|Single|
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|2|43|83|108|Single|
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|3|37|85|180|Single|
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|4|37|93|252|Single|
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|5|43|95|324|Single|
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|6|42|89|36|Single|

[META DATA]
01/10/2015|14:50:27|USA|UWI_N2C34_2|MMS1|FORD35|Bednarek|true|6|0|false|

[QUALITY CAMERA CHECK]
1|1|0|
2|1|0|
3|1|0|
4|1|0|
5|1|0|
6|1|0|

[PRESET]
S0M6A36A108A180A252A324A36|TA|
```

And i read line where iso country is held ( in this example `|USA|`) `01/10/2015|14:50:27|USA|UWI_N2C34_2|MMS1|FORD35|Bednarek|true|6|0|false|`

To do that I tried to use function group which is part of regular expression. I deduced that I need to read from specific line which hold this string. So I wrote small code:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import os
import string
import re
import sys
import glob
import fileinput
import shutil

country_pattern = 'MYS','IDN','ZAF', 'THA','TWN','SGP','CYP', 'NWZ', 'AUS','ALB','AUT','BEL', 'BGR', 'BIH', 'CHE','CZE', 'DEU', 'DNK', 'URY', 'ESP','EST','SRB','MDK','MNE','BIH', 'BIH','MNE','FIN', 'FRA', 'GBR','GRC', 'HRV', 'HUN', 'IRL', 'ITA', 'LIE', 'LTU', 'LUX', 'LVA', 'MDA', 'SMR','CYP','NLD','NOR','POL','PRT','ROU','SCG', 'SVK','SVN','SWE','TUR','BRA','CAN','USA','MEX','CHL','ARG','RUS'
pattern = r'(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\|(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\|(\S+)\|(\S+)\|(\S+)\|(\S+)\|(\S+)\|(\S+)\|(\d+)\|(\d+)\|(\S+)\|'


src = raw_input("Enter source disk location: ")
src = os.path.dirname(src)
for dir,_,_ in os.walk(src): 
    file_path = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir,"*.txt")) 
    print "file_path", file_path



    for file in file_path: 
    f = open(file, 'r')
    object_name = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    part = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(file)) 
    part_file1 = os.path.basename(part)
    part_file2 = os.path.split(part)[0] 
    print "part_file2: ", part_file2
    part_file3 = os.path.split(part)[1]
    print "part_file3: ", part_file3
    source = os.path.join(part_file2, part_file3)
    print "src", source
    file_source = glob.glob(os.path.join(source,dir))
    print "file_source", file_source
    for element in file_source: 
        final_file_source = element


    for line_name_tmp in object_name:
        line_name = line_name_tmp.replace(' ','')
        #line_name = line_name_tmp.replace('\n','')
        if line_name == '':
            line_name.split()
            continue
        else:
            pass
            try:
                searchObj = re.search(pattern, line_name)
                m = searchObj.group(7) 
                print "KRAJ : ", m
                if m in country_pattern:
                    path = os.path.join(part_file2, m)
                    print "PATH", path
                    print "ELEMENT", element

                    if not os.path.exists(path):
                        os.makedirs(path)
                    else:
                        pass
                    shutil.copy(element,path)
                else:
                    print 'did not find any match'
            except:
                print line_name
                pass
```

At the moment i am able to create empty folder automatically with names based on country ISO in text file. I tried to moved folders with it's content to locations  based on their country iso.

I tried to use function "shutil.copy" but nothing happend.

What i tried to do, is to move folders if they contain different countries in strings and seperate them to diffrent location. 
I hope you al understand my issue. I know it's pretty complex :)

Also basic directory looks like this:

```
E:\data\WE244JP_2015_04_01__13_43_59\WE244JP_2015_04_01__13_43_5.txt
E:\data\WE244JP_2015_04_01__14_43_59\WE244JP_2015_04_01__14_43_5.txt
E:\data\WE244JP_2015_04_01__15_43_59\WE244JP_2015_04_01__15_43_5.txt'
```

What i tried to do i move folders(along with it's content)  E:\data\WE244JP_2015_04_01__15_43_59 on this level to folder based on their country in txt

I had to edit this topic a bit for you ,to understand my problem now :)

Comment: So, you're looking through all files, checking the line containing the country code - then you want to move the file you just checked to another folder. Is that correct?

Comment: exactly this what i need. i want move it to another folder with the same name as country in text file

Comment: Hi, is anyone able to tell me how to solve this. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the way you are creating source. According to your code source is:

```
source = part_file2 + paryt_file3 = '//'
```

Assume your path  is C/D/E.txt then:

```
part = C/D/
part_file1 = E.txt #file you are working on
part_file2 = C
part_file3 = D
source = CD// #plus operator does a simple concatenation.
```

Now you are trying to move this source folder which doesn't even exists. This is the problem.

Edit:
shutil.move() will always move the entire directory for the code you have written. If you want to move only the files, use this piece of code:

```
src_files = os.listdir(src)
for file_name in src_files:
    file_path = os.path.join(src, file_name)
    if (os.path.isfile(file_path)):
        shutil.move(file_path, path)
```

Now we are moving file by file. This should work as expected

Comment: Ok i modyfied this line to  :  source = os.path.join(part_file2, part_file3), but still instead of moving content of folder, it moved me a whole folder which i do not want. How to move content of file ?

Comment: shutil.move will always move entire directory. If you want to move only the files; use the piece of code I have written in edit of the answer.

Comment: I found this piece of information - maybe it will help me - ? def ignore_pyc_files(dirname, filenames .. - source https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch13s07.html

Comment: Please accept the ans by clicking on the right mark near it if it was helpful. You can also choose to upvote